# Excel VBA - save as file with content from a specific sheet

Tags: vba

I'm trying to save as my Excel file into multiple xlsx files, soemthing like this:

[image]

I would like to save as it into multiple xlsx files with each file will content 1 line  range("Ax:Dx"). I have written the code as below to do that

```
Sub split_file()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastrow1 As Long
    Dim lastrow2 As Long
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    
    'Dim filename As String
    Path = "C:\test"
   For i = 2 To Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        'wb.Worksheets(3).Copy 'create new active workbook
        Sheets.Add.Name = Sheet2.Range("A" & i).Value
        With Worksheets(Sheet2.Range("A" & i).Value)
             Range("A1:D1").Value = Sheet2.Range("A" & i & ":D" & i).Value
            .SaveAs filename:=Path & "\" & Sheet2.Range("A" & i).Value, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Password:="Welcome1"
            .Close savechanges:=False
        End With
   Next i
   On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

The result I got is shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Once I open the file after save as with proper data, it include some unwanted sheets in that :( .

Like this:

[image]

I wish it save as only the file with the same name. Can anybody help look for this problem ?

Very appreciated for each support of you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next way:

```
Sub split_file()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet, wbNew As Workbook
    Dim path As String, i As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(Sheet2.Name)
    
    path = "C:\test"
    For i = 2 To ws.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
             Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
             Set wsNew = wbNew.Sheets(1): wsNew.Name = ws.Range("A" & i).value
             wsNew.Range("A1:D1").value = ws.Range("A" & i & ":D" & i).value
             wbNew.saveas FileName:=path & "\" & wsNew.Name, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, password:="Welcome1"
             wbNew.Close savechanges:=False
   Next i
End Sub
```

I assumed that `Sheet2` is a code name...

Comment: thank Bros, it work correctly.  BTW, can you please help comment for this line ? what is the target of this ? " Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) "

Comment: @thangvc91 It should create a new workbook with only one sheet... It opens a template sheet. Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlwbatemplate)...